# How to sum unique lines?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sum, unique

I'm trying to count the time used to collect each order since all orders are in batches - it goes under a different ID.

If i use `Sum(DateDiff(MINUTE, pick.pick_start_time, pick.pick_end_time As [Pick Total Time]`, it will output time 70. Which should be 14 since it shows the same time for each order, obviously because it was in 1 batch under ID 1.

Example below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/relAn.png)
Is there a way to count unique start time, end time so it would output 14 only?

Comment: You can use minimum of the start time and maximum of end time for a particular order .. This will give you the exact time taken to complete the order...
So.. in that function you can pass the minimum of pick_start_time and maximum of pick_end_time

Comment: Is there a way for you to distinguish different batches?

Comment: @dodekja as far as i understood, the first column is an ID. so all rows with same ID are part of one order

Comment: Yes.. based on the batch ID.. which would be unique.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Added picture to make it more accurate, expected result at Jed is 14, Jeva 8, Jesse 7.. but like i posted below with full code, i'm not counting just that

Answer (score 2):

A solution might be just calculating the time difference between minimal starttime and maximal endtime:

```
SELECT ID
      ,DateDiff(MINUTE,MIN(pick_start_time),MAX(pick_end_time)) AS [Pick Total]
  FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: The important thing for the OP to note here, is the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to work using that

Added full code to make more sense what i'm trying to do

```
Select
Distinct(pick.pick_start_time) as Start time
picker.pic_name As Picker,
Count(distinct(order_header.oh_order_number) As [Order QT],
Sum(pick_line.pickl_quantity) As [Total items],
SUM(DateDiff(MINUTE,MIN(pick_start_time),MAX(pick_end_time)) AS [Pick Total]

From delivery_header 
Inner Join
  (((pick_line 
    Inner Join
        pick On pick_line.pickl_pick_id = pick.pick_id) 
    Inner Join
      picker On pick.pick_pic_id = picker.pic_id) 
Inner Join
    (pack 
    Inner Join
      pack_line On pack.pack_id = pack_line.pl_pack_id) On pick_line.pickl_id =
      pack_line.pl_pickl_id) On delivery_header.dh_pack_id = pack.pack_id
    Inner Join
  order_header On order_header.oh_id = delivery_header.dh_oh_id


Where pick.pick_end_time >= @DateFrom And pick.pick_end_time <= @DateTo And
  (pick.pick_pic_id = @picker Or @AllPickers = 1)

Group By picker.pic_name
Order By picker.pic_name
```

Comment: As i'll have multiply order IDs, order numbers, pickers.. And i need to sum up whole picking time over each picker